# Attempting to list employee name and ID for employees working on a property in Seattle

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm supposed to use a subquery, but I'm not quite certain where I'm going with this.
I know that I need to match EmployeeIDs from the ggemployee table and the property_service table, then match the PropertyID from the property_service and owned_property tables, then make sure that the PropertyID is tied with the property in Seattle.

I'm just a bit lost with where I need to go from here.

This is the code I have now:

```
select ggemployee.LastName, ggemployee.FirstName, ggemployee.EmployeeID
from ggemployee
inner join property_service on property_service.EmployeeID = ggemployee.EmployeeID
inner join owned_property on property_service.PropertyID = owned_property.PropertyID
    and owned_property.PropertyName = 'Seattle';
```

I attempted to do this with join on syntax, but haven't quite got it working. If someone could show me the proper way to do this with *join on* and *subqueries* that would be absolutely amazing.

Thank you so much in advance for the help!

EDIT:
I also tried something like this..

```
select ggemployee.LastName, ggemployee.FirstName, ggemployee.EmployeeID
from ggemployee, property_service, owned_property
where property_service.EmployeeID = ggemployee.EmployeeID
    and property_service.PropertyID = owned_property.PropertyID
    and owned_property.PropertyName = 'Seattle';
```

EDIT2: I am dumb, PropertyName is supposed to be city. Sorry!

Comment: Totally rookie question I'm certain. Just getting back into SQL and I'm drawing blanks

Answer (score 0):

PropertyName need be changed to City. That fixes all issues.

Granted the proper way to use subqueries is the following:

```
select LastName, FirstName, EmployeeID
from ggemployee
where EmployeeID in
    (select EmployeeID from property_service where PropertyID in
        (select PropertyID from owned_property where city = 'Seattle'));
```